# Plotting multiple MCMC autocorrelations in the same figure

Tags: r, coda

The `coda` package gives us nice plots of traces, autocorrelations, densities and so forth. For the autocorrelations, we can do:

```
library(coda)
samples <- data.frame(rnorm(1000), rbeta(1000, 1, 2))
autocorr.plot(mcmc(samples))
```

[image]

But is there a straight way to plot all the correlations as lines in a single plot (with legend)? (I've seen doing this in some papers)